# Cannot find stored procedure even through it "already exists"

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, stored-procedures

New to mysql. Trying to create a stored procedure that I saw in this tutorial: http://www.microshell.com/database/mysql/emulating-nextval-function-to-get-sequence-in-mysql/

In order to load the procedure, I ran:

```
mysql -u root -pmypassword test_db < path/to/sproc/sequence_next_val.sql
```

It seemed to have worked, since every subsequent time I run it, I get:

```
ERROR 1304 (42000) at line 3: FUNCTION nextval already exists
```

However, when I go to the mysql command line, and do:

```
$ USE test_db
$ CALL nextval('sequence_name');
```

I get:

```
ERROR 1305 (42000): PROCEDURE test_db.nextval does not exist
```

mysql version info: mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Comment: A function and a procedure are two different things

Answer (score 2):

You've created a Function, and to use it you need to `SELECT nextval()`. If you create a Procedure, then you can use `CALL`.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

In your linked exercise it does this correctly:

`SELECT nextval('sq_my_sequence') as next_sequence;`